# Quintus Prolog installation

Tags: prolog

I am trying to install Quintus Prolog on Ubuntu Virtual Machine. But, I can't find this version of Prolog on the internet. I found only SICStus Prolog. But, after installing this version of prolog and tried to run an artificial intelligence program i am getting this error:

```
 Experience error in user:file_exists/1
    procedure user:file_exists/1 does not exist
    goal: user:file_exists('lattice.patches.pl')
```

Does anyone any idea about how can I solve this problem or how can I obtain a version of Quintus Prolog?

Comment: [Here](https://quintus.sics.se/) it is. [SICStus 4](https://sicstus.sics.se/) is its successor.

Comment: You need to say `use_module(library(file_systems))` to make `file_exists/1` work.

Comment: @false Thank you! I tried to execute the program like this: `use_module(library(file_systems)), build_lattice.`. Now I get this error: `user: writef/1 does not exists`. Do you have any idea about what should I include?

Comment: The 4.3.5 version of SICStus a am using and, my code is working when running with Quintus. But, when using SICStus a am getting this errors and I don't have a version of Quintus or any idea about how to solve this problem...

Comment: What version of Quintus did this code use? It must have been some very premature version from mid-1980s. Later versions do not offer `writef/1`. But they (and SICStus) have format/2 which is quintessentially the same. So define: `writef(F) :- format(F,[]).`

Comment: @false thanks again! You're right, it's a very old version of Quintus but, I don't know exactly how old it is. The only problem I've got now is with `count/1`. I included all the libraries from this site [link](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.3.0/html/sicstus/The-Prolog-Library.html) but no one it's working..